# Разница между платным и бесплатным хостингом

Tags: сервер, хостинг

Здравствуйте. Хотел задать вопрос, что отличает платный хостинг от бесплатного. Зачем нужно платить лишние деньги, если сайту и там хорошо?)) Какой вариант выбрать для сайта с посещаемостью 1000 человек? И зачем может понадобиться выделенный сервер.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Бесплатный хостинг чаще всего используется для обучения, тестирования кода, для временного размещения части проекта.
Список сайтов компаний предоставляющих услуги бесплатного хостинга:

- 000webhost.com
- 500mb.ru
- ucoz.ru
- narod.ru
- webservis.ru
- ho.ua
- hut.ru
- wallst.ru
- litehosting.ru
- awardspace.com
- eomy.net
- holm.ru
- ayola.net
- freehostia.com
- hostland.su

Возможные минусы бесплатных хостингов:

- Наличие рекламы.
- Неустойчивость работы сервера.
- Более строгие ограничения на ресурсы сервера(процессорное время, доступная оперативная память, постоянная память, количество запросов к БД и тп.).
- Критический лимит количества FTP, SMTP, DataBase(MySQL/MSSQL/postgreSQL) аккаунтов или даже их отсутвие.
- Отсутствие поддержки серверных ЯП(PHP, ASP.NET, Java, Python и тп.) или их компонентов/надстроек(в т.ч. CMS типа Joompla, Wordpress, Drupal, DLE не говоря уже про менее популярные)
- Ограниченный размер загружаемого файла.
- Запрещены некоторые расширения файлов.
- Тех. поддержка чаще всего отсутствует или работает не в полную силу.
- Часто отсутствие нормальной панели управления, планировщиков заданий и прочих вкусностей.
- Невозможность привязать внешний домен.
- Не солидность.
- Чаще всего можно прощаться со своим сайтом, если он чем-то не угодил хостеру. Вам никто ничем не обязан. Вас не будут спрашивать отключать сайт или нет. В лучшем случае дадут предупреждение или предложат заказать платные услуги.

Платный виртуальный хостинг обычно не имеет вышеуказанных недостатков. Он являться достаточно экономичным и идеально подходит под небольшие и средние проекты. Выбрать компанию-хостера рекомендую [тут](http://www.hosting-obzor.ru/index.php). Если же Ваш сайт: очень требователен к ресурсам/имеет большую посещаемость/требует дополнительного администрирования или тонкой настройки сервера то как вариант можно использовать виртуальный выделенный сервер или
выделенный сервер или даже облачный хостинг. Последние намного дороже виртуального хостинга.

---

Вы сами должны решить переносить ли сайт на платный хостинг. Я лишь указал на возможные минусы работы с бесплатным хостингом. Если же Вы нашли бесплатный хостинг без вышеуказанных недочетов, то пожалуйста сообщите об этом в комментарии к ответу, буду рад им пользоваться время-от-времени.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно же платных хостинг лучше, но проверенный, например Агава. На платном хостинге всегда готовая вам помочь техническая поддержка, работающая 24 часа в сутки, обычно у них и бесплатная с ними связь. Не на всех бесплатных хостингах есть подключение своего домена. Плюс бесплатные хостинги просят обязательного нахождения своего копирайта на сайте.

Answer (score 0):

сервис, отсутствие рекламы и наверно самое приятное - домен. Вообще, я не встречал бесплатных только хостингов =)

Comment: а IP адрес у всех разный или всех на один вешают?))

Comment: у бесплатных точно у всех один, доступ по домену, но за отдельную плату можно брать выделеный